# Different levels on unity game

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am planning to make a android game using unity game engine. I would like to include different levels as we see in angry birds and some other games. My question is whether I have to build different scenes for each levels. I am completely new to this platform.

Comment: short answer is yes, each level would be a new scene. You could of course reuse a lot of components from one scene to the next.  But each level would be a new scene.

Comment: Thanx man for ur valuable comment....my next doubt is that does it make any difference in game's size.

Comment: well yeah the more scenes the bigger the game will be, so you will want to reuse a lot of components/assets from one level to the next.  This will help keep the game small. if it's 2d like angry birds than a bunch of levels shouldn't be a huge deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes and no. It's possible to use just one scene and manage levels on your own, but this will add a lot of complexity, will be hard to manage and is generally not recommended. Though, this might be a viable option in some circumstances: for example, if you generate your levels procedurally.

That being said - you should use scenes to manage your levels, and Unity will take care of a lot of details, such as editing, loading, releasing unused assets when switching levels, etc, that otherwise you'd have to implement yourself.

You also shouldn't worry about scenes bloating your game, because they are quite small compared to game assets. They only contain information about what objects are in the scene and their properties. Also scenes include only references to assets (textures, meshes, sounds, prefabs, scripts and so on), and actual data is stored separately and shared between them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have complex objects like you know a lot of variations of enemies and objects then it is good to make different scenes for different levels.
On the otherhand if your levels have a little changes like enemy behavior changes movement changes etc then u can easily do it in one scene by passing variables of different object. 
But first approach is easy to use. 
here is a example of a game with SECOND APPROACH :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.batterylowgames.killyourbloodyfriends&hl=en

Thank you :)